# Unable to see Max in SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, graphdb, knowledge-graph

Im trying to  query a knowledge graph  and im trying print the max occurrence of ?n in the result and i have tried running following query but it just doesn't prints anything

here is my SPARQL Query

```
PREFIX : <http://www.tafsirtabari.com/ontology#>


PREFIX RDF:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>


select
?n
(MAX( xsd:int(?countOfSharedLikedItems)) as ?max) 
(COUNT(?n) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems)  

where {

?h :hasTheme :lugha .
?h RDF:type :Hadith .
?h :hasHadithNo ?o.



?p :isPartOfHadith ?h.
{
    ?p :hasNarratorSegment ?nc.
    ?nc :refersTo+/:hasName ?n.
}
Union
{
    ?p :hasRootNarratorSegment ?rnc.
    ?rnc :refersTo+/:hasName ?n.
}

 }
```

i have also tried following by using group by ?n

```
PREFIX : <http://www.tafsirtabari.com/ontology#>


PREFIX RDF:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>


select 
(MAX(?countOfSharedLikedItems) as ?max) 
(COUNT(?n) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems)  
where {
 ?h :hasTheme :lugha .
?h RDF:type :Hadith .
?h :hasHadithNo ?o.



?p :isPartOfHadith ?h.
{
    ?p :hasNarratorSegment ?nc.
    ?nc :refersTo+/:hasName ?n.
}
Union
{
    ?p :hasRootNarratorSegment ?rnc.
    ?rnc :refersTo+/:hasName ?n.
}

} group by ?n
```

[image: THIS IS THE RESULT OF THE ABOVE MENTIONED QUERY I JUST CANT SEE VALUES]

Comment: you'll need a subquery in which the counts are computed and in the outer query you can compute the maximum of all counts

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks for the response can you give me an example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
PREFIX : <http://www.tafsirtabari.com/ontology#>

select  (COUNT(?o ) AS ?triples) where {
 ?k :heardFrom ?o 
}

6. Which RAWI narrated most hadiths about TOPIC_A 

PREFIX hash: <http://www.tafsirtabari.com/ontology#>
PREFIX W3:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://www.tafsirtabari.com/ontology#>

SELECT  ?total WHERE{
select DISTINCT ?n (COUNT(?n) as ?total)  where {
    ?commentary hash:mentions hash:اهل_المعرفه .
   ?segment hash:containsCommentary ?commentary.
   ?segment ?Fr ?h .
    ?h W3:type hash:Hadith.
    ?p :isPartOfHadith ?h.
    {
        ?p :hasNarratorSegment ?nc.
        ?nc :refersTo+/:hasName ?n.
        
    }
    Union
    {
        ?p :hasRootNarratorSegment ?rnc.
        ?rnc :refersTo+/:hasName ?n.
    }
}GROUP BY ?n
}ORDER BY DESC(?total)
LIMIT 1
```